Android in App Subscription cases to be handle
I have 2 subscription in android
Basic One with 3 base plan  (less feature)
1 month prepaid
6 month prepaid
12 month prepaid
Premium one with 3 base plan  (more feature)
1 month auto renewal
6 month prepaid
12 month prepaid
Scenario 1 I have to upgrade  1 month basic to 12 month basic -- (this should work as extend mean increase end date)
scenario 2 I have to upgrade 1 month basic to 12 month premium -- (if user doing in between upgradation then  this system has calculate remaining duration as per new plan , add that much extra as subscription end date)
Also make sure for Scenario 2 , there should old subscription should be termination there is no 2 active subscription at same time
To achieve this Should I create 2 subscription,

Basic one - with 3 base plan( 1,6,12 month prepaid)

Premium one - with 3 base plan( 1 month renewal, 6 and 12 prepaid)


Or should I create single subscription with 6 based plan
1 month basic prepaid
6 month basic prepaid
12 month basic prepaid
1 month premium auto renewal
6 month premium prepaid
12 month premium prepaid
I don't want 2 active subscription at same time

You should create 2 separate subscriptions, that would be best in your scenarios. The in-app billing automatically detects when the user upgrade his plan from basic to premium. Although you need to code according to your cases. Reading this documentation will help you https://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/subscriptions#switch_plans_across_subscriptions_or_override_the_default_replacement_mode

Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
